# Write a formula for the second derivative $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(f\circ c) (t)$ using the chain rule twice

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $f: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be a $C^2$ function and $c(t)$ a $C^2$ curve.
>
> Write a formula for the second derivative $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}(f\circ c) (t)$ using the chain rule twice

So after the the first chain rule you should have $\left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial t}\right) + \left(\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial t}\right)$. Not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first derivative
$$\frac{d\ f(x(t),y(t))}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
For second derivative
$$\frac{d^2\ f(x(t),y(t))}{dt^2}=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg)+\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg)$$
$$=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg)\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg)+\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg)$$
where
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\bigg)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg)=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\bigg)=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}\frac{dy}{dt}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\frac{dx}{dt}$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\bigg(\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg)=\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$$